# Understanding the usage of get() in my sorting script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently found a code snippet that I would really like to understand:

```
var buttons = $('#fruit,#vegetable,#meat').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var classes = buttons.filter('.active').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join(',.');
    $('div.fruit,div.vegetable,div.meat').hide().
        filter('.' + (classes || 'none')).show();
});
```

The HTML code :

```
<div style="float:right; padding:25px;">
    <button id="fruit" class="active"><span>fruit</span></button>
    <button id="vegetable" class="active">vegetable</button>
    <button id="meat" class="active">meat</button>
</div>

<div>
       <p>Trying to use buttons as an "or" case rather than "and." When choosing fuit or vegetable, I want to see tomato as part of each list, <em>not just</em> when both are selected.</p>  

<div class="fruit">
    <p>apple</p>
</div>

<div class="vegetable">
    <p>pumpkin</p>
</div>

<div class="vegetable">
   <p>okra</p>
</div>

<div class="fruit">
    <p>orange</p>
</div>

<div class="meat">
    <p>beef</p>
</div>    


<div class="fruit vegetable">
    <p>tomato</p>
</div>    

</div>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/61nc1rpk/12/).

I do understand how all the methods work in jQuery like `toggleclass`, `filter` and `map`, I also understand how `join` works in JS, but in this particular example, I am not able to figure out how `get()` is working or rather what is it's usage in the script is.

I went through the jQuery documentation for [get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and I came across this method for the first time; to me, it seems it's very much similar to `eq()` in jQuery, but I am still not able to figure out why exactly `get` is being used in my example.

Can somebody explain this to me ?

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/map/, From docs _As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array._

Comment: @Satpal , eah i have seen such conventions :) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get` is used here, because `.map` returns a jquery style object which contains some functions and information about the contained data. But in this scenario only the values stored within the object (the class names of the active buttons) are wanted. `.get` is used to get an array containing the raw values and with `.join(",.")` the values from the array get concatenated to a string. This string then get's used to show all div's that should be active according to the selected buttons.